# Which schools did Scottish novelist Alexander Trocchi attend?

Tags: alexander-trocchi

In his article "Technique du coup du monde", published in *Internationale Situationniste* no.8 in January 1963 and in English translation as "[A Revolutionary Proposal: Invisible Insurrection of a Million Minds](http://www.notbored.org/invisible.html)", Scottish novelist Alexander Trocchi writes

> "It used to be said that the British Empire was won on the playing
> fields of Eton. During the 18th and 19th centuries, the British ruling
> class was formed exclusively in such institutions; the deportment they
> conferred on a man was vitally relevant to the growth of England at
> that time. **Unfortunately**, the situation at **Eton and similar
> establishments** did not **continue to inspire its own improvement**.
> Inertia set in. Forms that were **once fruitful** hardened until they were
> devoid of contemporary relevance." [emphasis added]

He seems to be ascribing a positive value to both the British Empire and the contribution that Eton College made to training the men who ran it. Eton College is a private English boarding school for boys aged 13-18, attended by 20 pupils who went on to become British prime ministers, including the present incumbent (Boris Johnson) and his most recent male predecessor (David Cameron).

My question is this: which schools did Trocchi himself attend? Did he go to Eton? Was he at a "similar establishment"?

Comment: There was a [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57747698#57747698) about the on-topicness of this question. While questions about an author's life *as it relates to their literature* are allowed, not all biography questions fall into this category. ([meta discussion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152)). The suggestion was made to move this to [history.se]. Do you think this question is a better fit here or there?

Comment: I don't wish to get involved in site management issues. The article is about culture and he was a literary figure. It probably relates to some of what he was trying to achieve in at least some of his novels, meaning it relates indirectly to his literature, but I don't know his work well enough to argue for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Glasgow University](https://www.universitystory.gla.ac.uk/biography/?id=WH25409&type=P), he attended [HillHead High School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillhead_High_School), which at that time was a grammar school, and later [Cally House School](https://movingimage.nls.uk/film/0288) while he was evacuated.

> Cally House was wartime evacuation school in Galloway and was Britain's first local authority co-educational boarding school for senior pupils.

The school was based in an 18th-century country house in Kirkcudbrightshire (now part of Dumfries and Galloway).

The fact that the Cally House school was a boarding establishment probably doesn't do a great deal to make it 'a similar establishment' to a Public School, though it may have had some similarities of experience in being set in grand old buildings and being on the spartan side.

[This film](https://scotlandonscreen.org.uk/browse-films/007-000-000-061-c) suggests that there was some attempt to engender some of the civic aspects of the Public School life, but the fact of both Cally and Hillhead being Co-educational will have made a big difference to the character of the places, the English Public schools at that time being single sex, I believe. It is also clear in the film that the pupil-Teacher ratios are typical of State School rather than Public School.

As @Mikado points out in comments, in Scotland our education system has always been different from that of our neighbours to the south. The Scottish curriculum tends to be broader, covering a wider swath of subjects in final exams. This would further have set his education apart from pupils at Eaton, Rugby et al. Though *had* he attended a fee-paying school such as Gordonstoun, it is likely he’d have followed an English curriculum.

Comment: Ah, Kirkcudbrightshire, that famous red herring of pronunciation.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I did one hear a BBC radio person of some sort make reference to ’church-could-bright’.

Comment: For those who are not aware, the Scottish education system is very different from the English education system, another  factor taking Trocchi's experience further away from Eton.

Comment: @mikado fair point. I think the curricular differences would pale in comparison to other issues, the great public schools of England groom for leadership and government in a way that’s somewhat divorced from the mere acquisition of qualification. But not everyone will be aware so I’ve added a reference in. Cheers